# Showing that $\overline{ T(B_{X,1}(0))}$ in a Banach space $Y$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Consider the following problem. If I have Banach spaces $X,Y$, and an operator $T\in B(X,Y)$, how would I show that,

*"If $T\in B(X,Y)$, and $p\in\overline{ T(B_{X,1}(0))}$ then $-p\in\overline{ T(B_{X,1}(0))}$."*

I understand that I am trying to show that $\overline{ T(B_{X,1}(0))}\subset Y$ is convex, for $-p,p\in \overline{ T(B_{X,1}(0))}$, and I also understand that $\overline{ T(B_{X,1}(0))}$ is a closed set in $Y$ (since we are dealing with the closure).

However, I am not too sure where the point about $T$ being a bounded linear operator comes in. Could somebody please give me some direction for this problem?

Comment: The unit ball is convex, a linear transformation applied to a convex set yields a convex set and the closure of a convex set is again convex. Boundedness of $T$ is irrelevant.

Comment: It's just the fact that it is mentioned in the question makes me think I should make use of the fact.

Comment: In fact, convexity is not necessary here either. Just the facts that the unit ball is symmetric and $T$ is homogeneous are sufficient.

Comment: Right, as copper.hat pointed out, this has nothing to do with the boundedness of $T$. Nor do $X$ nor $Y$ need to be a Banach space--probably, being a locally convex space would be sufficient.  Maybe just even a TVS.  At any rate, if $p$ lies in the closure of $TB_{X,1}(0)$, can you find a sequence in $B_{X,1}(0)$ that might help?